# Samsung Galaxy Note 4 goes standby when idle, pauses apps

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

Hello Android enthusiasts,

I have the following issue:
I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 and I have not turned on any power saving setting, however I cannot figure out for the life of me how to prevent my phone from automatically going into stand by mode (screen powers down, apps pause, GPS stops working, etc) when I haven't interacted with the phone for roughly 15 seconds or so.

I would like only this to happen when I press the power button. This greatly interferes with any app I use when I'm on the move (Pokemon Go, for example) and I don't want to poke the screen every 5-10 seconds or so so the app doesn't just stop functioning normally.

Please advise me on how I can prevent this. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.

Settings -> Display and Wallpaper -> Screen timeout - set it from whatever seconds to 10 minutes.